# Third party tool for custom login in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows, windows-7, api, authentication

Is there a tool that will allow the integration with a local script or a remote API for validating the user credentials?

Basically, I'd like for the user to get the regular logon screen, except that the username and password that they input will be validated by a custom script that I can configure. (something like [VSUsbLogon](http://www.lokibit.com/products.htm) - except that I need custom script, not an USB key).

Comment: This seems quite powerful: https://github.com/pgina/pgina/ - I'm checking it now.